# Generating random names from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I'm wanting to read a list of forenames and surnames from a plist I have created, and then randomly select both a forename and a surname for a 'Person' class.

The plist has this structure;

```
Root (Dictionary)
-> Names (Dictionary)
--> Forenames (Array)
---> Item 0 (String) "Bob"
---> Item 1 (String) "Alan"
---> Item 2 (String) "John"
--> Surnames (Array)
---> Item 0 (String) "White"
---> Item 1 (String) "Smith"
---> Item 2 (String) "Black"
```

I have been able to output all the keys for the dictionary, but I am unsure of how to grab the 'Forenames' or 'Surnames' key and then store this in an array.

The code to output all the keys is a simple output to the log.

ie;

```
// Make a mutable (can add to it) dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;


// Read foo.plist
NSString *path      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.plist"];

dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

// dump the contents of the dictionary to the console
for (id key in dictionary)
{
    NSLog(@"Bundle key=%@, value=%@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);      
}

NSMutableArray *forenames;

// This doesn't work, it outputs an empty array
forenames = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Forenames"];
NSLog(@"Forenames:%@", forenames);
```

Questions;

1. How do I make my NSMutableArray *forenames take the contents of the dictionary 'Forenames'?
2. Once I have stored both the forename and surname in their own NSMutableArrays, I need to randomly select both a forename and a surname; what's the best way to do that?

The idea is that I can create a Person.m file with a Forename/Surname class variables and I can create randomly generated people.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it was implied, but does the dump of the dictionary's contents appear as expected? Is all this code part of the same method? Also, it's worth noting that the arrays stored in the newly created dictionary are immutable, so you have to call `mutableCopy` on them if you want to be able to modify them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the structure of your plist, I think you need to do one more level of dereferencing:

```
NSDictionary *names = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Names"];
NSMutableArray *forenames = [[names objectForKey:@"Forenames"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *surnames = [[names objectForKey:@"Surnames"] mutableCopy];
```

Then you can use `srandom` and `random` to generate random indices into your arrays. The general way of generating a random number on [0,N) is this:

`NSUInteger i = (NSUInteger)((random()/(double)RAND_MAX)*N);`

Replace N above with a call to an array's `count` and you'll be set.

By the way, I can't see a reason for creating a mutable copy of the name arrays. I just wanted to illustrate how you'd do it. Also, you need to seed with `srandom(time(NULL));` to get different random values each time your program runs.

Comment: I'll try that. I wasn't aware I had to use mutableCopy on them, but I'll try it and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: That worked great, I was able to randomize a firstname and a surname and dump them to the log.

Thanks for your help. I think the mutableCopy stuff threw me.